# Creating Swipe with undefined pages

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe, android-fragmentactivity

So, I want to create a swipe activity but it will have unlimited pages (fragments). The idea is to create some kind of calendar, and when the user scrolls right, it will go to the next day and when left, it will go to previous one. Im asking for some guidelines to do so. I believe I have to create a layout (known as fragment maybe ?) for my day, inflate it on an adaptar and set that adapatar to my day activity. Am I right ? Any hint about what to do next ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some library available already like
[Caldroid third party library](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)

and if you want to do it by your own use ViewPager with fragmentStatePager adapter [ViewPager with fragmentstatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)